Similarity of non-standard matrices
I am researching numerical methods for PDEs. I particular, I am looking at methods for the linear hyperbolic PDE
$$
u_t+au_x=0.
$$
This is a common approach, because successful methods for this model problem often generalize to more complex examples. I am following the standard von Neumann analysis, which assumes

a regular Cartesian grid $x_j=j\Delta x$,
a time step $t^n=n\Delta t$
a structure $u_j^n=g^ne^{ij\theta}$ for the sought for discretized value (the complex amplification $g$ then emerges as the eigenvalue of a complex matrix).

I have found two seemingly very different methods whose matrix representations have the same eigenvalues and therefore the methods are similar is some sense. However, a formal procedure to find a change-of-basis matrix has failed. I attribute this to the elements of my matrices not being drawn from a field. Is there perhaps some other concept of matrix similarity that could apply to my situation?
EDIT-ATTEMPTED CLARIFICATION
I have gained enough knowledge of abstract matrix theory to partially recognize how badly posed my question was. Let me try again. In the theory of numerical PDEs, von Neumann analysis relates the discrete solutions at two consecutive time steps and is the go-to method for studying accuracy and stability. We have $\mathbf{u}^{n+1}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u}^n$ where $\mathbf{u}$ is a vector of complex numbers whose real parts are the discrete solution. The matrix $\mathbf{A}$ has entries that are also complex numbers, so superficially we deal only with matrices over the field $\mathit{C}$.
However, the entries in $\mathbf{A}$ are only of interest if they can be interpreted as finite difference operators, meaning that they are polynomials in the shift operator $T$
whose FFT is $e^{i\theta}$. Since the group of complex polynomials is not closed under division we do not in fact have a field, but in early application of vN analysis, the characteristic polynomial was always reducible to linear factors. Each of these gave a finite difference operator applying to one characteristic variable of the PDE under study.
vN analysis has been also been applied to numerical methods in which the discrete solutions are no longer represented by vectors of complex scalars, but by lists of complex numbers representing approximations to various moments such as moving integrals and derivatives. For example, discontinuous Galerkin, Hermite, and Active Flux methods. In these cases, the characteristic polynomial is usually irreducible, and the corresponding "eigenstructure" cannot be interpreted in terms of finite-difference operators. What puzzles me is that the "eigenvalues" still seem to make experimental sense, at least as far as indicating the limits of stability. And I have found, as I said, two seemingly quite different numerical methods that have the same characteristic polynomial, but apparently no similarity in the change-of-basis sense.
Textbooks seem to treat vN analysis as a way to derive useful results without delving into their correct interpretation. My guess at the moment is the analysis treats the smooth interpolants without requiring them to be polynomial but perhaps of some more general form. My REVISED QUESTION is whether any of the above makes sense in the general context of matrices over rings, or are there perhaps no general results that apply? As @Andrei Smolensky has suggested, is everything so dependent on features of the specific ring that nothing can be said without that knowledge?
Since posting the question, I have dipped my toes into the sea of literature concerning
matrices over rings, and have indeed found it be vast. My initial impression is that it is also rather sprawling and incoherent, so can anyone recommend anything to read? My education is that of a typical PhD in Engineering, but I have a substantial research record in Numerical Analysis, particularly of PDEs.

It would certainly help if you provided more details. Studying matrices over rings is a vast subject, and a lot of things depend heavily on the type of the base ring.

@Andrei. Thanks, I am vaguely aware of the vastness. I had hoped that describing the background would provide enough context, but since this is not the case, could you please describe the sort of detail that would be helpful? I can of course provide the 2x2 example.

Well you said that you are dealing with matrices with entries not in a field - but where do the entries come from? And how to you find the eigenvalues then?

The entries are finite-difference operators, expressed as polynomials in the shift operator. Addition and subtraction are defined, and multiplication as concatenation. But division and square root only occasionally make sense. Eigenvalues come out in the usual way and are complex numbers representing the phase and amplitude changes in a sinusoidal signal after one time step. These make sense and correspond with numerical experiment.
